# How to calculate frequency of this Op Amp square wave oscillator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, waveform, single-supply-op-amp

I was trying to come up with the equation to calculate the frequency of this circuit.
R1 and R2 are creating analog ground because I am using bipolar op amp for a single supply operation.
[image]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ form a divider. Why don't you start by simplifying the circuit using the Thevenin equivalent? What have you done or tried, on your own? Also look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311143/how-to-determine-resistor-value-for-given-voltages/311194#311194) to better understand how \$R_3\$ interacts.

Comment: The frequency is dependent on R3 R4 and C. I don´t really have a lot of experience in electronics I just don´t know where to start. Thank you for that link.

Comment: Well. Is this homework? Because, if so, shouldn't they have provided you with the tools needed to know where to start? (The general solution to this problem sounds a lot more like busy work handed out at a school.) Or do you have a specific application in mind that you haven't discussed yet? If you do, what's the voltage rail voltage?

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-multivibrator.html

Comment: its a relaxation oscillator circuit. usually the amp is a comparator.

Comment: @AntonínGazda use KVL and KCL and you should be able to determine the voltage at each node. Then, apply ideal conditions for the OPAMP, where \$V^{+}\$ = \$V^{-}\$ and  \$i^{+}\$= \$i^{-}\$=0. Show us some work from your side

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion from previous answers, I would add that your circuit is precisely a *relaxation oscillator*. For instance, the TLV3501 is a rail-to-rail high-speed comparator, suitable to be used in this particular application

[image: Relaxation Oscillator TLV3501]

Refs:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sis3.png) [TLV3501 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3501.pdf?ts=1664862959783&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253DTLV3501AIDBVT%2526nr%253D8)

extracted from page 13 from the datasheet. The analysis isn't too complicated. You can replace the capacitor with a voltage source to get a better picture of the thresholds the comparator is working with.

Answer (score 0):

You should easily be able to calculate the min and max voltage at the positive terminal of the (assumed ideal) op amp based on the resistor values R1-3 and the supply voltage... (Unknown, but will fall out of the math later).

The capacitor will charge and discharge with a time constant of C x R4 ..
It will charge to the high voltage at the op amp's positive terminal and discharge to the low voltage. Voltage at the capacitor will be equal to the supply voltage x 1 - e raised to the power of negative time divided by the time constant above... if I recall Electrical engineering 101 ... So basically solve the equation twice, once for the high voltage and once for the low voltage. The result will be the high output pulse and low output pulse widths. Add for the period of oscillation... Now add a buck and you can have a Tall Starbucks... or buy me one.

Comment: So if the voltage is 5V and 0V the frequrncy should be 1/(2*R4*C)? Is that right? Assuming R1 = R2 = R3 (thats how I have it in my circuit)

Comment: @AntonínGazda I don't think so, because there is a missing factor there. Why don't you post your math as an addition to your question.